# My Five - stores five names and five numbers before being promoted for a number need input

Tags: python-3.x

For class I need to create a code that stores five names of your friends and five numbers in two separate arrays and then outputs the list of your five friends. The user would then be prompted for a number between 1 and 5, and the program will determine the person and the number to dial.

it should look something like -

```
1. Jack Black
2. Robert Downey Jr.
3. Chris Evens
4. Scarlett Johansson 
5. Harry Potter

Please enter a number (1-5): *4*

Calling Scarlett Johansson at 416-568-8765
```

right now I have:

```
name = ["Paige"]
number = ["519-453-4839"]

#populate with a while loop
 while True:

      #add an element or q for quit
       addname = input("Enter a name, or q to quit ").lower()
 
 if addname == "q":
     break
 else:
     theirnumber = input("Enter their number ")
     #adds to the end of the list
     name.append(addname)
     number.append(theirnumber)

#when they break the loop
#print the lists side by side
 print()
 print("Name \t\t\t Number")
 print("----------------------------------")
 for x in range(len(name)):
     print(f"{name[x]} \t\t\t {number[x]}")

 #search for a gift and who gave it
 searchItem = input("What name are you looking for? ")
 if searchItem in name:
     nameNumber = name.index(searchItem)

     print(f"{name[nameNumber]} is the number {number[nameNumber]}")
 else:
     print("that is not a saved name, please enter a different name")
```

I'm not sure how to do it without asking for the numbers, if anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.

Comment: It seems that the requirement asks you to create a `mapping` or `lookup` first: for the names->numbers.  Once you have it  (the `lookup`), then you can just issue the `query` for the person.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two arrays you can do it using Python Dictionaries.
Use the name as the key and the number as the corresponding value.

```
peoples = {"Paige": "519-453-4839"}
```

You can add an item like that:

```
poeples["newName"] = "111-111-1111"
```

Then you can access the number like that:

```
peoples["Paige"]
```

So you can ask the name and return the number:

```
searchName = input("What name are you looking for? ")
print(f"{searchName} is the number {peoples[searchName]}")
```

If you have to use only arrays then you can find the index from the name:

```
searchName = input("What name are you looking for? ")
index = name.index(searchName)
print(f"{name[index]} is the number {number[index]}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it how I want it

Comment: Hi @Mitzy33, if you have accepted one of the posts as it's helpful, please ✅ it and acknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

@Mitzy33 - try to this and see if you follow, or have any other questions:

```py
# two array for names, and the numbers
names = []
numbers = []

#populate with a while loop
while True:
     # get the name and numbers:

    name = input("Enter a name, or q to quit ")
     
    if name == "q":
        break
    else:
        number = input("Enter his/her number ")
        #adds to the end of the list
        names.append(name)
        numbers.append(number) 

#when they break the loop
#print the lists side by side
print(names)
print(numbers)

searchPerson = input("What name are you looking for? ").strip()

#print(searchPerson)

index = names.index(searchPerson)

print(f' {searchPerson} at {numbers[index]} ')
```

Output:

```
Enter a name, or q to quit John
Enter his/her number 9081234567
Enter a name, or q to quit Mary
Enter his/her number 2121234567
Enter a name, or q to quit Ben
Enter his/her number 8181234567
Enter a name, or q to quit Harry
Enter his/her number 2129891234
Enter a name, or q to quit q
['John', 'Mary', 'Ben', 'Harry']
['9081234567', '2121234567', '8181234567', '2129891234']
What name are you looking for? Harry
 Harry at 2129891234
```